# Convert EPS to PNG and specify width/height

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, eps

How to convert an EPS file to PNG and specify the size of the PNG?

```
convert file.eps -resize 800x1200 file.png
```

This converts the EPS but with the wrong dimensions

sample EPS file
https://ufile.io/zrv3n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either ignore aspect ratio with `!`

```
convert file.eps -resize '800x1200!' file.png
```

Or resize to fill, and clip to size.

```
convert file.eps -resize '800x1200^' -gravity Center -extent 800x1200 file.png
```

Other techniques covered in [Resize or Scaling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) article.

Answer (score 3):

In ImageMagick, the proper way to change output raster size when converting an EPS to PNG is to specify -density before reading the EPS. For higher quality, you can then resize after using a large density value. For example:

```
convert -density 300 file.eps -resize 800x1200 file.png
```

You can force the dimension to be exact with distortion or crop or pad as per emcconville's answer.